# My Files is running very slow

Tags: file-system, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

When I open up `My Files` and select `All Files` the phone is `processing` for multiple minutes until i can do anything. It says `Verwerken...` in dutch (Processing). Once done after a moment it does the same.

It is impossible to browse the files on my phone this way. Is there a fix to this? The phone is brand new.

Comment: There are probably thousands and thousands of files in 'All Files' especially with no filter at all. Would you not just go by folder for navigating? If there is no filter, every single sound file, dex, image, video, temp file, text file, saved games, apks, EVERYTHING has to be looked up across the entire device. It also depends on how fast / powerful the device is. Mind you if brand new I would expect it to be fastER than a few minutes to be honest. Have you tried ES File Manager or an alternative to `My Files` which could just be a badly made app?

Comment: @RossC On my S4 there is absolutely no problem. What do i have to select otherwise? I can go to images, videos, music, documents and otherwise all files. What i am trying to do is deleting some APK's I downloaded.

Comment: Yeah I would definitely try another app then. ES File Manager is a fantastic piece of software (I'm not affiliated with it at all) and might be a better way to go about things. My Files is not something I have on any of my devices, but I have had issues with some file managers (especially CyanogenMod's one which is painfully slow)

Comment: I would recommend Xplore file manager. It's great and very light. Been using it from my S60 days.